# Highchart, polar chart multiple values in one line

Tags: charts, highcharts

I have a simple HighChart polar chart, which shows some data. 
Problem is, that i want too show date of each data selected from DB, how to do this?

[image]

```
  series: [{
        name: 'Allocated Budget',
        data: [43000, 19000, 60000, 35000, 17000, 10000],
        pointPlacement: 'on'
    }]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/49Lkgdr0/

Comment: Where you keep this data? In data point or in categories? Because in your example this dates are missing.

Comment: That is the point, i dont know where to place them.

Comment: All depends on in which format you return data from your database. You can for example return each point as an object like {x: "11.1.2016", y:43000}

Comment: Can you show me example please? `data: [{x: "11.1.2016", y:43000}],` this doesnt work in my example

Comment: My bad, should be name instead of x. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xqwu650b/

Comment: Awesome, right what i need. Please, rewrite your message to classic answer, then i can mark it as solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your date as category (name param in each point)

```
data: [{name: "11.1.2016", y:43000}]
```

and then extract that information in tooltip.pointFormat.

```
pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>${point.y:,.0f}</b><br/><b>Date: </b>{point.name}'
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xqwu650b/